# How to interpret a Green's function containing a branch cut from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ at negative imaginary frequency?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fluid-dynamics, condensed-matter, greens-functions, effective-field-theory

From some loop calculation in an EFT, I have found the Green's function containing this square root:
$$G(\omega, k)\sim \sqrt{\frac{D k^2 \tau- (i+\tau \omega)^2}{(i+\tau \omega)^2(-D k^2 \tau + \omega \tau (2 i + \tau \omega))}}$$
I need to find $G(t, k)$.  However, Mathematica command "InverseFourierTransform" cannot do this. Therefore, I restrict myself to the special case $k=0$
$$G(\omega, 0)\sim \sqrt{\frac{-1}{\omega \tau (2 i + \tau \omega)}}$$
Even in this case, "InverseFourierTransform" doesn't work. By $3D$-plotting of the Re and Im parts of $(\omega,0)$, I found that its analytical structure is a bit strange: there are two branch cuts, one starting from $0$ to $-2i/\tau$ and the other from $-\infty-i/\tau$ to $+\infty-i/\tau$ (see below). I want to understand what is the meaning of a branch cut from -infinity to +infinity at a negative imaginary frequency? In particular, this becomes important when one wants to find $G(t,0)$ by closing the integral contour in $G(t,0)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} G(\omega,0) e^{- i \omega t}$  on the lower half of the complex frequency plane.

[image]

If anyone could comment on this issue I would be grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Up to rescaling, you are studying the function:
$$
\hat G(\omega) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\omega(\omega+i)}}
$$
The natural cut to choose is the segment $[0,i]$. It's what the program tried to do, but due to automatic choice of the branch for the square root, there are the artificial branches that appeared. The Fourier transform:
$$
G(t) =\int \frac{d\omega}{2\pi}\hat G(\omega)e^{-i\omega t} 
$$
can be calculated using contour integration.

For $t<0$, you need to close the contour on the upper half complex plane, so you get
$$
G(t) = 0
$$

For $t>0$, you need to close the contour on the lower half complex plane. You can deform it to "snugly" encompass the branch cut to get:
$$
\begin{align}
G(t) &= \frac{1}{\pi i}\int_0^1 \frac{e^{-xt}dx}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}} \\
&= -ie^{-t/2}I_0\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)
\end{align}
$$
with $I_0$ the modified Bessel function of the first kind (courtesy of Wolfram Alpha...).

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is really helpful @LPZ. Based on your explanation, I think the point is that I don't need to necessarily follow Mathematica's choice of branch cut. Great!